# Does Modern Warfare 3 use dedicated servers on the PC?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Does the multiplayer mode of the PC version of *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3* use dedicated servers?

As an extra, is there a site that lists all the *MW3* server providers approved by Activision for each region? I remember such a list existed for Black Ops even before it launched, and people could even request additional servers for their region.

Again, talking about the PC version.

*The reason I ask is that I had serious lag problems with Black Ops. I eventually tracked the problem to the fact that all servers in my region were from the same provider, and that was the only approved provider.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern Warfare 3 does indeed support dedicated servers (see [here](http://community.callofduty.com/thread/4682)):

> **Will Modern Warfare 3 have Dedicated Servers?**
>
> Yes! Modern Warfare 3 supported matchmaking as well as Dedicated Servers, allowing players to find and filter via an in-game server browser or set-up their own Dedicated Server for complete control, without being restricted by any 3rd party hosting requirements. If looking for a Dedicated Server to join, if you choose not to set up your own, you can filter and favorite by Ping, Map, Gametype, Hardcore Variants, Voice, Password, and many other options.

As for an approved server list, it appears the ranked servers are managed in-game (you have to enable browsing of dedicated servers in the options to even see those); I'll update if I find anything.

Comment: Remember, you don't accrue XP when using dedicated servers!

Comment: @JarrodMosen among the disappointments I've had with MW3, this is the largest.